# SMS url on android with ionic 3 framework not opening messaging app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

The sms url works fine on iOS and opens the messages app fine but on android it does not open the messages app and just crashes.  Does anyone know why its not opening the messages app on android?

home.html

```
<h5 class="padding5"><a [href]="sanitize('sms:' + 1234567890)"><ion-icon class="contactIcons" name="text"></ion-icon></a></h5>
```

home.ts

```
  sanitize(url: string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the forward slashes to your sms link like so:

```
<a [href]="sanitize('sms://' + 1234567890)">
```

Also be sure to allow intent in your config.xml:

```
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
```

Comment: I tried doing what you said but its still not working.  I get this error: `net::err_unknown_url_scheme(sms://1234567890)`

Comment: Have you checked what format of string the sanitize function is expecting? That is the proper way to pass sms to element in ionic. You may need to pass the string to sanitize then add the slashes after it is sanitized, then set that reference in the view.